# Как создается cтек в C#/Java ?

Tags: c#, java, стек

Привет всем софорумцам! Немного пожив на этом форуме понимаешь, что здесь обитают очень умные люди, которые помогают добрым словом другим не таким умным людям как я, по этому заранее всем спасибо ...
Собственно проблема: из всех доступных материалов мне понятно что такое стек и куча, но не понятно как она появляется, при запуске моей программы кто делает стек и кучу в оперативной памяти, операционная система? 
Например, запускаю я свою программу написанную например на C#, то ОС феерически быстро выделяет отрезок памяти под "стек" и "кучу" в ОЗУ, создаётся "процесс" все локальные переменные и объекты там размещаются и начинается работа программы ?

Comment: А зачем вам? Стек, как и куча — лишь подробности реализации. Вам [не нужно](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) думать в терминах стека.

А в чём проблема быстроты выделения? Ну, какой-то кусок памяти назначили стеком, почему на это нужно много времени?

Comment: @VladD, я просто хочу понять как это всё работает не более того ... Я не могу что-то сделать пока не пойму саму суть происходящего, возможно у меня проблемы с абстракцией в целом !

Comment: @Алина, можете почитать книгу Operating system concepts (9th Edition), она есть на рутрекере. Она не отвечает непосредственно на данный ваш вопрос, но содержит в себе ответы на очень многие похожие вопросы.

Comment: @Алина_Климова: нужная абстракция такова (в C#): элемент ссылочного типа, на который у вас есть ссылка, гарантированно жив. Если ссылки нет, может в любую секунду умереть (а может и не умереть, никто не гарантирует). Элементы типа-значения гарантированно живут пока есть возможность к ним получить доступ. Затем, при копировании переменной ссылочного типа копируется ссылка, а объект остаётся тот же, а при копировании типа-значения создаётся новый объект.

Больше не нужно вообще ничего, этих знаний достаточно.

Comment: Я поняла, большое всем спасибо ! Иногда удивляюсь откуда вы всё это знаете :)

Comment: офтопом, я бы Вам посоветовал еще прочитать, что такое алокатор, так на многое глаза открывает.)

Comment: @JEcho, хорошо, благодарю за помощь в моём обучении ...

Comment: @VladD оговорка про C# весьма к месту.

       элемент ссылочного типа, на который у вас есть ссылка, гарантированно жив

Можно вспомнить про языки/системы со слабыми ссылками...

Comment: @alexlz: в Java различные типы слабых ссылок лишь намекают сборщику мусора на желательность сборки данного объекта. Но точно так же есть сильная ссылка => объект гарантированно жив, нету сильной ссылки => объект может в любую секунду исчезнуть, в зависимости от обстоятельств. Плюс типами-значениями являются в Java лишь примитивы (`int`, `double`, ...)

Comment: @Алина_Климова, еще на эту тему можно почитать `man sbrk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общих чертах именно так.

ОС выделяет виртуальное адресное пространство процессу и частично заполняет его. Остальная память (реальное отображение виртуальных адресов на физические) будет выделяться по мере необходимости при работе программы.

Обычно стек и куча выделяются с разных концов адресного пространства и могут расти навстречу друг-другу.